# Tapestry - executed method for an event

Tags: java, methods, tapestry

Im working with Tapestry.
I need the Eventhandler method before the eventhandler is executed.

I found ComponentRequestFilter but there i may only get the ComponentEventRequestParameters . I dont know how to extract the eventhandlermethod from there. I could try to build the method name, but then i wouldnt cover @Onevent.
I have read the source code of tapestry for > 2 h, but i couldnt find any relevant piece of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically put, you can't. Tapestry "triggers" the event on a component, and searches the component, it's base class, and any mixins (and base classes) for event handler methods. You don't ever directly invoke a method (it is not a one-to-one mapping).

Generally, this kind of query is fruitless ... I can't imagine WHY you would need this information (what event, as if there was only one, will be invoked). Instead, what is your real requirement ... what are you trying to do?

You may have better luck on the Apache Tapestry user mailing list, as well.

Comment: Im trying to be able to secure eventhandlers.I know there are Chenillekit and tapestry-security, but theres no real documentation. Chenillekit doesnt looks like it will get an update and tapestry-security is "too big". I need a possibility to secure my mehtods, but i dont need apache shiro. I thought this could be easily done by checking at the right position, but that doesnt seems true. I wanted to get the method name to get the method to check for the existence of an annotation. But "you can't" helps mee too because i dont have to search for a solution in this way any more.

Comment: Do you think my goal is reachable by using class transformations?

Comment: Yep, definitely possible with class transformers. Have a look at the source code of tapestry spring security (from the nu.localhost website), the SpringSecurityWorker class in particular. If you are using Tapestry >= 5.2, you will have to check the source out from the repository. The code still isn't ported over to use the new PlasticClass libraries, but it should give you a good starting point none the less.